# What is the easiest way to check if it is the first sheet of the workbook using openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I want to differentiate what I do on the very first worksheet only on the workbook that contains more than 100 sheets.

One of the very first checks I do when I iterate through sheets in the workbook, is to check if it is the first worksheet. Using openpyxl, I have tried iterating through workbook using

```
for sheets in wb.sheetnames
```

So I can check if the first sheet is named 'Sheet1" but it is not working.

I tried just normally iterating through with

```
for sheets in wb.worksheets
```

and seeing if the sheet is wb[0] but that was not the answer either.

What is the if statement I can use to check whether the current sheet, while iterating through the workbook, is the first sheet?

e.g.

```
for sheets in wb.worksheets
    if sheet.sheetname == 'Sheet1':
        do this
```

Thank you!

Comment: Test the sheets Index [`wb.Index(sheets)`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html)?

Answer (score 0):

what happes if you do

```
for sheet in report.worksheets:
    if sheet == report.worksheets[0]:
        do stuff
    do other stuff if not first worksheet
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I needed to know.